# Git tree hash id generation

Tags: git

At first initialize a repo containing a file named rose

```
$: echo sweet > rose
$: git init
$: git add .
$: find .git/objects/ -type f
.git/objects/aa/823728ea7d592acc69b36875a482cdf3fd5c8d
$: git commit -m "rose"
$: find .git/objects/ -type f -printf "%h%f %s\n"
.git/objects/05b217bb859794d08bb9e4f7f04cbda4b207fbe9 49
.git/objects/aa823728ea7d592acc69b36875a482cdf3fd5c8d 21
.git/objects/665d02ccbacdde1c0f2eecde01fbf47144ddd492 124
```

Then I want to sha the blob and see how to generate tree-object's id

```
echo -e "tree 21\0100644 rose\0aa823728ea7d592acc69b36875a482cdf3fd5c8d"|sha1sum
```

What it print is not `05b217bb859794d08bb9e4f7f04cbda4b207fbe9`
Where am i wrong?

Comment: At the very least, your length in the header is incorrect.  That payload is more than 21 bytes for certain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`echo` inserts a newline by default, unless you specify the `-n` (omit newline) flag.

Also, the blob ID is not stored in ASCII format, but rather as binary value. This results in a object size of 32 (not 21).

The following command will give you the correct output:

```
echo -en 'tree 32\x00100644 rose\x00\xaa\x82\x37\x28\xea\x7d\x59\x2a\xcc\x69\xb3\x68\x75\xa4\x82\xcd\xf3\xfd\x5c\x8d' | sha1sum
```

Comment: thank's @knilttl , How is it obtained the size of the tree (number 32)؟

Comment: @Behnam you count the number of characters in the object: `100644 …\x5c\x8d` are exactly 32 characters

Answer (score 3):

The object ID in the tree is not stored in that format. Have a look:

```
git cat-file tree 05b217bb859794d08bb9e4f7f04cbda4b207fbe9 | od -c
```

Rather the tree data is a sequence of `<mode> SP <filename> NUL <hash>`, where `<mode>` is string-form mode, and `<hash>` is the 20-octet SHA1.

Answer (score 2):

The format of a tree object is as follows:

```
tree SIZE\0ENTRIES
```

`SIZE` is the size of the tree.
`ENTRIES` is a sequence where each element represent an object referenced by the tree.
Each object entry is formatted as follows:

```
MODE NAME\0BSHA
```

`MODE` is:

- 100644 for a normal file,
- 100755 for an executable file,
- 120000 for a symbolic link,
- 040000 for a tree object.

`NAME` is the directory or file name.
`BSHA` is a binary representation of the object ID.

With respect to the example by the OP, let us get a reference to the upper tree (master branch):

```
$ git write-tree
05b217bb859794d08bb9e4f7f04cbda4b207fbe9
```

While I will use this tree-ish, what follows applies to every tree.
The first 6 characters (`05b217`) are sufficient.

The tree content  in human readable format is given by:

```
$ git ls-tree 05b217
100644 blob aa823728ea7d592acc69b36875a482cdf3fd5c8d    rose
```

You may replace `git ls-tree` with `git cat-file -p`.

The binary format is *similar* to that given by:

```
$ git cat-file tree 05b217
100644 rose ▒▒7(▒}Y*▒i▒hu▒▒▒▒▒\▒%
```

The actual content has also the initial string `tree [content size]\0`.
To get it you might uncompress the file storing the tree inside the `.git` folder, using the 2/38 hash format:

```
$ openssl zlib -d -in .git/objects/05/b217bb859794d08bb9e4f7f04cbda4b207fbe9
tree 32 100644 rose ▒▒7(▒}Y*▒i▒hu▒▒▒▒▒\▒%
```

Given the objects stored in the tree and available via `ls-tree`, one might generate the (actual) content stored with an awk script:

```
$ git ls-tree 05b217 | awk -b 'function bsha(asha)\
{patsplit(asha, x, /../); h=""; for(j in x) h=h sprintf("%c", strtonum("0x" x[j])); return(h)}\
{t=t sprintf("%d %s\0%s", $1, $4, bsha($3))} END {printf("tree %s\0%s", length(t), t)}'
tree 32 100644 rose ▒▒7(▒}Y*▒i▒hu▒▒▒▒▒\▒%
```

To better understand the output, I produce a version of it  using escape sequences:

```
$ git ls-tree 05b217 | awk -b 'function bsha(asha)\
{patsplit(asha, x, /../); h=""; for(j in x) h=h sprintf("%s", "\\x" x[j]); return(h)}\
{t=t sprintf("%d %s\0%s", $1, $4, bsha($3))} END {printf("tree %s\0%s", length(t), t)}'
tree 92 100644 rose \xaa\x82\x37\x28\xea\x7d\x59\x2a\xcc\x69\xb3\x68\x75\xa4\x82\xcd\xf3\xfd\x5c\x8d%
```

Compare this output with the previous output from `git ls-tree 05b217`.

I now come to the  **tree hash generation** using different methods.

Using the file stored version of the tree:

```
$ openssl zlib -d -in .git/objects/05/b217bb859794d08bb9e4f7f04cbda4b207fbe9 | shasum
05b217bb859794d08bb9e4f7f04cbda4b207fbe9 *-
```

Using my awk-generated content:

```
$ git ls-tree 05b217 | awk -b 'function bsha(asha)\
{patsplit(asha, x, /../); h=""; for(j in x) h=h sprintf("%c", strtonum("0x" x[j])); return(h)}\
{t=t sprintf("%d %s\0%s", $1, $4, bsha($3))} END {printf("tree %s\0%s", length(t), t)}' | shasum
05b217bb859794d08bb9e4f7f04cbda4b207fbe9 *-
```

And finally the `git mktree` command:

```
# git ls-tree 05b217 | git mktree    
05b217bb859794d08bb9e4f7f04cbda4b207fbe9
```

The hash obtained is always the same.